# Automapper: Mapping a property value of an object to a string

Tags: automapper

Using Automapper, how do you handle the mapping of a property value on an object to an instance of a string.  Basically I have a list of Role objects and I want to use Automapper to map the content of each "name" property to a corresponding list of string (so I just end up with a list of strings).  I'm sure it has an obvious answer, but I can't find the mapping that I need to add to "CreateMap" to get it to work.

An example of the relevant code is shown below:

```
public class Role
{
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   ...
   ...
}

// What goes in here?
Mapper.CreateMap<Role, string>().ForMember(....);

var allRoles = Mapper.Map<IList<Role>, IList<string>>(roles);
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I love Automapper (and use it in a number of projects), but wouldn't this be easier with a simple LINQ statement?

```
var allRoles = from r in roles select r.Name
```

The AutoMapper way of accomplishing this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Role, String>().ConvertUsing(r => r.Name);
```

Comment: In this instance you are probably right and it would fit in with our infrastructure, but even so I'd be interested in knowing if/how it could be done with Automapper.

Comment: Sorry -- should have answered your original question.  :)

This should work: Mapper.CreateMap<Role, String>().ConvertUsing(r => r.Name);

Comment: Thanks for providing an Automapper way of doing this, it works exactly as I'd hoped.

Comment: How do you do the reverse, setting the role from the string?

Comment: @Chris -- assuming you have access to the roles object: roles.Single(r => r.Name == roleName).

Comment: @Chris -- Automapper way to do the reverse: Mapper.CreateMap<string, Role>().ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src)) should work I think.